# Replicate focus function with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I want to replicate the below function with vanilla javascript, I have tried to .focus() event but it's not working the same.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try using `tabIndex="1"` on an element which you want to focus and then apply the `.focus()` function

Comment: I don't see how moving the input to a different place in the tab order would help.